# Convert byte[3] to byte[2] in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I currently have a list of byte arrays with 3 bytes in it. This array needs to be converted to a byte array with 2 bytes, and the range should be scaled so the values fit inside 2 bytes.

It is okay to loose some precision as long as the values are all scaled with the same amount.

Comment: You have a list of byte arrays: `var input = new List<byte[]>() { new byte[3] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 }, new byte[3] { 0x4, 0x5 } }` and you want to convert it into a byte array with 2 bytes: `var result = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x0 }`. This is what I've understood of your question so far, and I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve. I don't know what the list of arrays represents, what the bytes represent, or what the resultant 2-byte byte array contains or how that relates to the input.

Comment: "range should be scaled", what does that mean? How does "3 bytes" have a range, other than 0-255,0-255,0-255 ?

Comment: Every 3 bytes are converted to a single int, this int is used to plot a graph, I have to save the 3 bytes int as a 2 bytes int and make sure the graph still looks the same when plotted

Comment: @Timo Please show an example input and output, that would be helpful

Comment: Update your question with the relevant information.This lacks massive amounts of detail which are only contained in your thoughts

Comment: So you have a 24-bit number stored in 3 bytes, and you want to convert it to a 16-bit number stored in 2 bytes, is that right? Are these numbers signed or unsigned?

Comment: Given your comment, do you mean you want to convert the 3 byte arrays into 2 byte arrays (as opposed to a single 2-byte array as suggested in your question)? Assuming that's correct, is Matthew's idea right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you could go about converting bytes to integers and back to bytes as follows:

```
var input = new byte [] { 0x45, 0x67, 0x89 };

// Depending on byte order, use either the first or second conversion
var converted1 = ((int)input[0] << 16) | ((int)input[1] << 8) |
                  (int)input[2];
var converted2 = ((int)input[2] << 16) | ((int)input[1] << 8) |
                  (int)input[0];

// Not sure what kind of scaling you want, here I just shift right
var scaled1 = converted1 >> 8;
var scaled2 = converted2 >> 8;

// Convert back to a byte array
var output1 = new byte [] { (byte)(scaled1 >> 8), (byte)(scaled1 & 0xff) };
var output2 = new byte [] { (byte)(scaled2 & 0xff), (byte)(scaled2 >> 8) };
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** changed bitwise AND to OR in `converted1` and `converted2`. Thanks to @AleksAndreev for pointing out my error!

Comment: Thanks you, this was wat i needed.